# Button Autolayout programmatically?

Tags: swift, uibutton, autolayout, constraints

Hey guys I want to position my Button at the lower part of the Screen but I don't get the correct code. The button is too small, too big, at the right or left corner,... but It should be centred in the middle of the lower screen.

I tried it with these codes:

```
nextButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        nextButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
        nextButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
        nextButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: 97)
        nextButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, constant: 50)
```

or

```
backButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
       backButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
       backButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
       backButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

Can someone tell me what to do to make it work? I thought with the topAnchor it would be really easy:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will position it in bottom center of screen

```
nextButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    nextButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
    nextButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant:-20),
    nextButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
    nextButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50) 
])
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using centerYAnchor instead of bottomAnchor

Replace

```
nextButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
```

with

```
let spacingConstant = 10.0
nextButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -spacingConstant)
```